# Como notificar o rastreamento dos correios ao usuário?

Tags: php, magento, web-service

Possuo um *eCommerce* que em partes se integra aos **Correios**, exceto o sistema de rastreamento que apenas incluo o código de rastreio na ordem. Preciso que a cada alteração do status, o cliente seja notificado via e-mail.

Com o código abaixo, eu consigo fazer uma consulta ao serviço dos Correios e posso verificar o retorno do STATUS.

```
$error = array();

$url = 'http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList';
$url .= '?P_LINGUA=001&P_TIPO=001&P_COD_UNI=' . $code;
try {
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client();
    $client->setUri($url);
    $content = $client->request();
    $body = $content->getBody();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error[] = $e;
    return false;
}
```

Porém, dessa forma eu devo estar fazendo a verificação periodicamente (12h,24h) e consultando cada código. Há alguma forma de estar recebendo apenas o retorno dos códigos que houve de fato alteração, e ter apenas um *observer* tratando-os? Ou a única forma será com um script meu, configurado ao *CRON*, estar consultando o código e fazendo a devida manipulação do retorno?

Comment: Já fiz isso convertendo o HTML do track em hash, e inserindo no db para comparação, se o hash mudar, faço o envio do novo status via email e guardo novamente o hash do HMTL, e o agendamento no cron a cada 4h

Comment: No seu caso houve algum problema com isso?

Comment: Até hoje não, mas só faço a leitura do que esta dentro da tag table! Ex.: preg_match( '/<table  border cellpadding=1 hspace=10>.*<\/TABLE>/s', $this->html, $this->table ), E roda até hoje, mas você pode guardar os dados se quiser também, e fazer rotina de verificação pela ultima data da ocorrência. Se a data for maior do que esta no banco, faça o insert ou update, e envia novamente.

Comment: @Coringa pode responder com a sua dica?

Comment: Vou postar um exemplo básico, mas em OPP, ae você adapta ao seu código!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiz o exemplo básico para você entender a lógica, de **duas formas**, `Track do HTML` e dos `Objetos` em `array` para armazenamento em Banco de dados, e o hash para comparação do mesmo no DB!

```
<?php

class Tracking {

    public $track;
    public $table;
    public $erro = false;
    public $erroMsg = false;    

    /**
    * Construtor
    *
    * @param string $track Código da encomenda
    * return void
    */
    public function setTrack($track=false){

        if ( strlen($track) !== 13) {
            $this->erro = true;
            $this->erroMsg = 'Código de encomenda Inválido!';
        }
        $this->track = $track;

    }

    public function trackHTML()
    {
        if( $this->erro === true ):
            return $this->erro;
        else:

            $url = 'http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_TIPO=001&P_COD_UNI=' . $this->track;
            $html = utf8_encode( file_get_contents( $url ) );

            if (strpos($html, "src=../correios/") !==false) {
                $html  = str_replace('src=../correios/',
                    'src=http://websro.correios.com.br/correios/', $html );
            }

            preg_match( '/<table  border cellpadding=1 hspace=10>.*<\/TABLE>/s', $html, $table );

            // hash para monitoramento de alteração de status
            $this->hash = md5($html);           

            return ( count( $table ) == 1 ) ? $table[0] : "Objeto não encontrado";

        endif;
    }


    public function trackObject(){

        $html = utf8_encode( file_get_contents('http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_TIPO=001&P_COD_UNI=' . $this->track ));

        // Verifica se o objeto ainda não foi postado, caso seja o caso, retorna erro e mensagem
        if (strstr($html, '<table') === false){
            $this->erro = true;
            $this->erroMsg = 'Objeto ainda não foi adicionado no sistema';
            return;
        }

        // hash para monitoramento de alteração de status
        $this->hash = md5($html);

        // Limpa o codigo html
        $html = preg_replace("@\r|\t|\n| +@", ' ', $html);
        $html = str_replace('</tr>', "</tr>\n", $html);

        // Pega as linhas com o rastreamento
        if (preg_match_all('@<tr>(.*)</tr>@', $html, $mat,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
            $track = array();
            $mat = array_reverse($mat);
            $temp = null;
            // Formata as linhas e gera um vetor
            foreach($mat as $item){
                if (preg_match("@<td rowspan=[12]>(.*)</td><td>(.*)</td><td><FONT COLOR=\"[0-9A-F]{6}\">(.*)</font></td>@", $item[0], $d)){
                    // Cria uma linha de track
                    $tmp = array(
                        'date' => $d[1],
                        'DateSql' => preg_replace('@([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})@', '$3-$2-$1 $4:$5:00',$d[1] ),
                        'local' => $d[2],
                        'action' => strtolower($d[3]),
                        'details' => ''
                    );

                    // Se tiver um encaminhamento armazenado
                    if ($temp){
                        $tmp['details'] = $temp;
                        $temp = null;
                    }

                    // Adiciona o item na lista de rastreamento
                    $track[] = (object)$tmp;
                }else if (preg_match("@<td colspan=2>(.*)</td>@", $item[0], $d)){
                    // Se for um encaminhamento, armazena para o proximo item
                    $temp = $d[1];
                }
                $this->status = $tmp['action'];
            }
            $this->track = $track;
            return $this->track;
        }

        // Caso retorne um html desconhecido ou falhe, retorna erro de comunicação
        $this->erro = true;
        $this->erroMsg = 'Falha de Comunicação com os correios';

    }   

}
```

Instanciando a classe

```
$track = new Tracking();
$track->setTrack('PI205094504BR');

if($track->erro !== true){

    echo $track->trackHTML();

    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Hash para monitoramento de alteração de status: ';
    echo $track->hash;

} else {
    echo $track->erroMsg;
}
```

Neste Exemplo o resultado é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No segundo exemplo, retorna os dados em array

```
if($track->erro !== true){

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $track->trackObject() );
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Hash para monitoramento de alteração de status: ';
    echo $track->hash;

} else {
    echo $track->erroMsg;
}
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 20/07/2015 14:04
            [DateSql] => 2015-07-20 14:04:00
            [local] => CTCE VITORIA/GCCAP - Viana/ES
            [action] => postado
            [details] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 20/07/2015 22:00
            [DateSql] => 2015-07-20 22:00:00
            [local] => CTCE VITORIA/GCCAP - Viana/ES
            [action] => encaminhado
            [details] => Encaminhado para CTE BENFICA - Rio De Janeiro/RJ
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 21/07/2015 16:55
            [DateSql] => 2015-07-21 16:55:00
            [local] => CTE BENFICA - Rio De Janeiro/RJ
            [action] => encaminhado
            [details] => Encaminhado para CTCE CUIABA - Varzea Grande/MT
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 24/07/2015 15:35
            [DateSql] => 2015-07-24 15:35:00
            [local] => CTCE CUIABA - Varzea Grande/MT
            [action] => encaminhado
            [details] => Em trânsito para AC DIAMANTINO - Diamantino/MT
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 28/07/2015 09:48
            [DateSql] => 2015-07-28 09:48:00
            [local] => Diamantino/MT
            [action] => saiu para entrega ao destinat��rio
            [details] => 
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 28/07/2015 16:59
            [DateSql] => 2015-07-28 16:59:00
            [local] => AC DIAMANTINO - Diamantino/MT
            [action] => entrega efetuada
            [details] => 
        )

)

Hash para monitoramento de alteração de status: ccebc8ce6343aea4692500bae90a49d3
```

Neste exemplo usei `file_get_contents`, mas normalmente uso `cURL`

Comment: tudo bem? Qual a possibilidade de eu te pedir uma ajuda por e-mail, sobre esse código.Caso tenha custo podemos negociar..rsrs.. Na verdade gostaria de uma aula para me ensinar a fazer e entender como foi feito, pois estou aprendendo a desenvolver em PHP.
Desde já muito obrigado pela atenção.
Rodrigo Pais